# Logic Apps - Stop Blob triggers running on weekends

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which is triggered when a blob is added or modified.  It checks every few minutes.  Given that logic apps are charged for each run of the Trigger (I think), how can I stop the Trigger running at weekends?  I can't see anything on  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage)

Comment: Hi AIHal, do you mind disable it manually on weekends by clicking the "Disable" button in the "Overview" of your logic app ?

Comment: If it can't be done automatically that is what I will need to do.  I thought there may be an automatic way of doing this eg with an Azure function or going into code view.

Comment: Hi AIHal, I have provided two solutions below for your reference. But I think maybe the second solution suits you better because the first solution could be a little difficult. Please check~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [azure timer trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function) with the cron expression to schedule the function run every Friday evening and call this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/disable) in the timer trigger function to disable your logic app.

For example, the cron expression could be:

```
59 59 23 * * Fri
```

Then create another timer trigger function with the cron expression to schedule the function run every Monday morning and call this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/enable) in the timer trigger function to enable your logic app.

For example, the cron expression could be:

```
0 0 0 * * Mon
```

**Another solution:**

You can add a condition after the blob trigger(before the actions which the logic will do), shown as below:
[image]
The expression of "dayOfWeek()" is:

```
dayOfWeek(utcNow())
```

In the response of dayOfWeek() method, Sunday --> 0, Monday --> 1.

So in the conditon above, most of the actions will just run on Monday to Friday. On Saturday and Sunday, you will just pay for the trigger but not for most of the actions in your logic app. But you need to pay attention to the time zone if use this solution. You an know more information about the pricing of logic app in this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/logic-apps/).

**By the way, I think the second solution may suit you better. Because in first solution we can't call the api easily in azure function, we have to get the access token(in [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)) before request the api.**

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Powershell to disable you Logic App. One option to run it is from Azure Functions with Managed identity, which you can give permissions to the required Logic Apps.

```
Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "MyLogicApp" -State Disabled -Force
```

And to enable, just switch the State option to "Enabled"